# jQuery remove string from string doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everytime an certain image is clicked I fetch some information, to add that information to a string and after that replace the current url with the new one. This is my code so far:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var kleuren = [];
    jQuery('.swatch-category-container img').click(function(){


        var kleur = jQuery(this).attr('title');
        console.log("Selected kleur: " + kleur);
        var link = jQuery(this).closest('.popup').find('.photo a').prop('href');
        kleuren.push(kleur);
        console.log(kleuren);
        console.log(kleuren.length);
        console.log("Fetched link: " + link);
        var length = kleuren.length -1;
        var avoid ="?kleur="+kleuren[length];

        console.log("Remove string: " + avoid);

        var news_link = link.replace(avoid,'');
        var new_link = news_link + "?kleur="+kleur;

        console.log("Cut string: " + news_link);

        jQuery('.photo').find('.sendkleur').attr("href", new_link);


    });
});
```

This works fine, but the previous data doesn't get removed.

For example

When the first image is clicked the `kleur = zwart` that info is put in the url. 
But when the user clicks another image after that the url will look like `?kleur=zwart?kleur=beige` instead just of `?kleur=beige`

How can I remove the first part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although we could debug the replacement logic, I think I'd come at this a totally different way: Have a `data-*` attribute on the link that gives the raw version without `kleur`, then just reuse that; you can even initialize it on the first pass so you don't have to update your markup:

```
var linkElement = jQuery(this).closest('.popup').find('.photo a');
var link = linkElement.attr("data-rawhref");
if (!link) {
    link = linkElement.attr("href");
    linkElement.attr("data-rawhref", link);
}
// ...add kleur to `link`
```

If you don't need it to actually be an attribute, you can use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) instead, but there's probably no real advantage over the above as the link is just a string.

```
var linkElement = jQuery(this).closest('.popup').find('.photo a');
var link = linkElement.data("rawhref");
if (!link) {
    link = linkElement.attr("href");
    linkElement.data("rawhref", link);
}
// ...add kleur to `link`
```

---

But the problem with your code is that you're using the *current* `kleur`, rather than the old one, in `avoid`:

```
kleuren.push(kleur);                 // Pushes the current kleur at the end
var length = kleuren.length -1;      // Will be the index of the *current* kleur
var avoid ="?kleur="+kleuren[length];// ...and so this is looking for the wrong one
```

instead:

```
var avoid, new_link;
if (kleuren.length) {
    avoid = "?kleur="+kleuren[kleuren.length - 1];
    new_link = link.replace(avoid,'') + "?kleur="+kleur;
} else {
    new_link = link + "?kleur="+kleur;
}
kleuren.push(kleur);
```

That's assuming you really need an array of previously-selected colors. If you don't, just use a variable:

```
var avoid, new_link;
if (letzteKleur) {   // Meant to be "last color", my German is non-existant
    avoid = "?kleur="+letzteKleur;
    new_link = link.replace(avoid,'') + "?kleur="+kleur;
} else {
    new_link = link + "?kleur="+kleur;
}
letzteKleur = kleur;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But one question where and how do I define letzteKleur?

Comment: @user3164891: Where you currently have `kleuren`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you never do a pop on the array?
How does your log look like?
It seems that you try to replace the current value not the previous.

```
kleuren.push(kleur);
console.log(kleuren);
console.log(kleuren.length);
console.log("Fetched link: " + link);
var length = kleuren.length -1;
var avoid ="?kleur="+kleuren[length];
```

maybe that will do (of course only if there is at least 1 item in the array)

```
console.log(kleuren);
console.log(kleuren.length);
console.log("Fetched link: " + link);
var length = kleuren.length -1;
var avoid ="?kleur="+kleuren[length];
kleuren.push(kleur);
```